Angular Error: NG8002: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. [plugin angular-compiler] // Import declaration is made
I have declared ReactiveFormsModule in my app.module.ts like so:
app.module.ts
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AllocationFormComponent } from './allocation-form/allocation-form.component';
import { AppHeaderComponent } from './app-header/app-header.component';
import { AllocationHistoryComponent } from './allocation-history/allocation-history.component';
import { AppHomeComponent } from './app-home/app-home.component';
import { AppNavigationComponent } from './app-navigation/app-navigation.component';
import { AllocationOptInComponent } from './allocation-opt-in/allocation-opt-in.component';
import { AllocationOptOutComponent } from './allocation-opt-out/allocation-opt-out.component';
import { AllocationResponseComponent } from './allocation-response/allocation-response.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AllocationFormComponent,
    AppHeaderComponent,
    AllocationHistoryComponent,
    AppHomeComponent,
    AppNavigationComponent,
    AllocationOptInComponent,
    AllocationOptOutComponent,
    AllocationResponseComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormControl,
    FormGroup,
    FormBuilder,
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

My component is tied to an app router.  The component files look like this...
allocation-form.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgFor } from '@angular/common';
import { PotentialInvestment } from '../models/potentialInvestment.model';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-allocation-form',
  templateUrl: './allocation-form.component.html',
  styleUrl: './allocation-form.component.scss'
})
export class AllocationFormComponent {
  //Form Controls
  //onSubmit(allocationsSelectionForm: NgForm) {
  //  const bypassDecision = allocationsSelectionForm.form.value.rdoBypassAllocation;
  //  const regularDecision = allocationsSelectionForm.form.value.rdoRegularAllocation;

  //  console.log(bypassDecision, regularDecision);
  allocationsSelectionForm = new FormGroup({
    rdoBypassAllocation: new FormControl(''),
  });
  //}
  //END OF: Form Controls


  //Visibility Cascading Tree
  blockTwoVisibility = false;
  bypassRotationCommentsVisibility = false;
  blockThreeVisibility = false;

  Visibility(blockName: string) {
    if (blockName == "blockTwo") {
      this.blockTwoVisibility = this.blockTwoVisibility = true;
    }
    else if (blockName == "bypassRotationComments") {
      this.bypassRotationCommentsVisibility = this.bypassRotationCommentsVisibility = true;
    }
    else if (blockName == "blockThree") {
      this.blockThreeVisibility = this.blockThreeVisibility = true;
    }
    else if (blockName == "submit") {
      this.blockTwoVisibility = this.blockTwoVisibility = false;
      this.blockThreeVisibility = this.blockThreeVisibility = false;
      this.bypassRotationCommentsVisibility = this.bypassRotationCommentsVisibility = false;
      //Submit payload to backend - Call another TypeScript method here

    }
  }
}

allocation-form.component.html
<form [formGroup]="allocationsSelectionForm">
    <!-- Block 1 -->
    <div class="centerWithBorder">
      <p>How are you submitting your Potential Investment for allocation?</p>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button class="affiniusButton" (click)="Visibility('blockTwo')">Manual Entry</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- This will occur in phase #2 -->
        <!--<tr>
          <td>
            <input type="button" id="btnAPIEntry" class="button" disabled="disabled" value="Pipeline Entry (Disabled)" />
          </td>
        </tr>-->
      </table>
    </div>
    <!-- Block 2 -->
    <div class="centerWithBorder" *ngIf="blockTwoVisibility">
      <p>Does the Potential Investment need to bypass rotation?</p>
      <div class="form-wrapper">
        <div class="form-row">
          <label>Bypass Allocation: </label>
          <input id="rdoBypassAllocation" formControlName="rdoBypassAllocation" type="radio" value="Bypass Allocation" (click)="Visibility('bypassRotationComments')" ngModel  />
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <label>Regular Allocation: </label>
          <input id="rdoRegularAllocation" name="rdoRegularAllocation" type="radio" value="Regular Allocation" (click)="Visibility('blockThree')" ngModel />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="centerWithoutBorderOutline" *ngIf="bypassRotationCommentsVisibility">
        <div class="form-wrapper">
          <!--<div class="form-row">-->
          <label for="bypassAllocationComments">Bypass Allocation Reason:</label>
          <textarea id="bypassAllocationComments" name="bypassAllocationComments" rows="4" cols="200" onfocus="this.value=''">Provide detailed comments for Fund Managers to review.</textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <button class="affiniusButton" (click)="Visibility('blockThree')">Add Allocation for Bypass</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>

When trying to run the app, I am getting this error message.
Application bundle generation failed. [1.545 seconds]

X [ERROR] NG8002: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/allocation-form/allocation-form.component.html:1:6:
      1 │ <form [formGroup]="allocationsSelectionForm">
        ╵       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  Error occurs in the template of component AllocationFormComponent.

    src/app/allocation-form/allocation-form.component.ts:8:15:
      8 │   templateUrl: './allocation-form.component.html',
        ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


X [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-app-navigation' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-app-navigation' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-app-navigation' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.component.html:0:0:
      0 │
        ╵ ^

  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

    src/app/app.component.ts:9:15:
      9 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


X [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-app-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-app-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-app-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.component.html:2:0:
      2 │ <app-app-header></app-app-header>
        ╵ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

    src/app/app.component.ts:9:15:
      9 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


X [ERROR] NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.component.html:3:0:
      3 │ <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        ╵ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

    src/app/app.component.ts:9:15:
      9 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Watch mode enabled. Watching for file changes...

From my own troubleshooting, I have found that
X [ERROR] NG8002: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. [plugin angular-compiler]

Is almost always caused by the app not importing the ReactiveFormsModule into the app.module.ts.  I am doing this, and then importing it on my component's .ts file as showcased above.
Additionally, if I do a template driven form, I do not encounter any errors, it is only when I work with a Reactive angular form.
EDIT:
I also wanted to include my app.component.ts file
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppNavigationComponent } from './app-navigation/app-navigation.component';
import { AppHeaderComponent } from './app-header/app-header.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  title = 'allocations.client';
}

Additionally, here is my app-routing-module.ts file:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AllocationFormComponent } from './allocation-form/allocation-form.component';
import { AppHeaderComponent } from './app-header/app-header.component';
import { AllocationHistoryComponent } from './allocation-history/allocation-history.component';
import { AppHomeComponent } from './app-home/app-home.component';
import { AppNavigationComponent } from './app-navigation/app-navigation.component';
import { AllocationOptInComponent } from './allocation-opt-in/allocation-opt-in.component';
import { AllocationOptOutComponent } from './allocation-opt-out/allocation-opt-out.component';
import { AllocationResponseComponent } from './allocation-response/allocation-response.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    //canActivateChild: [MsalGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: AppHomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: AppHomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'form',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: AllocationFormComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'history',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: AllocationHistoryComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'response',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: AllocationResponseComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'optin',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: AllocationOptInComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'optout',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: AllocationOptOutComponent
      },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }


Why are you importing FormControl, FormGroup and FormBuilder? Those are classes / services which don't need to be added to the imports array

Removing those fixed my issue.  Still very new to Angular and though everything needed to be imported that I was going to be using in my typescript.  Thank you @JSON Derulo.

Great! Actually I wasn't so sure if it would solve your issue, so I only added it as a comment. Now that it actually fixed your problem, I added an answer, backed up by information from the official docs. I would appreciate if you accept the answer by clicking the check icon at my answer.

You need to remove FormControl, FormGroup and FormBuilder from your module's imports. Only other modules or standalone components / directives / pipes can be imported. However, FormControl and FormGroup are just basic TypeScript classes and FormBuilder is an Angular service. They don't belong to the imports. More information can be found in the docs.
